# Not enough values when returning a duplicate count

Tags: oracle, plsql, duplicates

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Iracle which should return a count of duplicate records from a single table.

I am trying to return the result of that count back to the user. At the moment I am getting the error "**Error(6,78): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values"**

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DUPLICATECHECK (p_result OUT number)  
IS
theResult number;
BEGIN
   SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, COUNT(1) as "Duplicate Found" INTO theResult 
   FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
p_result := theResult;
END DUPLICATECHECK;
```

Comment: Use count(*) instead of count(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, COUNT(1) as "Duplicate Found" INTO theResult
```

Specifically, you're putting 3 different columns into one result, you do not have enough values.

As you're only looking for one value though you should select only that value

```
select count(*)
  into p_result
  from ( select first_name, last_name
           from employee
          group by first_name, last_name
         having count(*) > 1 )
```

If you have to use a procedure you can select directly into the OUT parameter, there's no need for a local variable. Why are you using a procedure rather than a function though?

Putting this together you get:

```
create or replace function duplicatecheck ( 
         p_result out number ) is
begin

    select count(*)
      into p_result
      from ( select first_name, last_name
               from employee
              group by first_name, last_name
             having count(*) > 1 )

end duplicatecheck;
```

If you really want to enforce uniqueness you should create a [unique constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datainte.htm#CNCPT1642) though I would recommend against this; there's no guarantees you won't have two employees with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, I am experimenting with Oracle PL/SQL. How would i execute the function or store procedure within Oracle SQL Developer? Would something like this work?

       `var myResult integer;
       execute duplicatecheck(:myResult);
       print myResult;`